# How to highlight the first inserted node in a tree view?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have an application with two forms. The first form is used to create `TreeView` nodes programmatically, and the second form has the actual `TreeView`. When the application loads I create two root nodes in the `TreeView`.

My problem is when I create my first sub-node for either of the root nodes, it is not highlighted. I give the Form and the `TreeView` focus, and also disabled the `HideSelection` property for the `TreeView`.

Once I add a another sub-node to either of the root nodes is when the inserted node becomes highlighted. I want each inserted node to be highlighted once it has been inserted, but that only works after the first one has been inserted.

Example Code:

```
m_ObjectAnimationForm.tr_vw_ANIMATION_OBJECT_LIST.SelectedNode = m_ObjectAnimationForm.tr_vw_ANIMATION_OBJECT_LIST.Nodes["OBJECTS_ROOT"].Nodes.Add(NewObject.ID, NewObject.ID);
```

I create a new tree node using the ID of the object for the 'KEY' and the string of the node, then that function returns the newly created tree node, making it the selected node in the tree.

After that code I call:

```
m_ObjectAnimationForm.tr_vw_ANIMATION_OBJECT_LIST.ExpandAll();
m_ObjectAnimationForm.tr_vw_ANIMATION_OBJECT_LIST.Focus();
```

Comment: Is that form visible by the time this code runs?  Why doesn't it already have the focus?  Favor Select() over Focus().

Comment: I found out using Select() did the trick. I had to call the form's Select(), then call the treeview's Select() to get it to work correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a slightly different setup, in which I control the highlighted item in the TreeView, by way of selecting an item in a datagridview.  It is not the most elegant methodology, but it works.

In Summary:

1.) Get Index from Source TreeView, Other Control, or elsewhere
2.) Expand all Nodes in Target TreeView
3.) Iterate through Tree Nodes in Target, until Index is Reached
4.) Set TreeView.SelectedNode = "the node that was found"
5.) Set Focus on TreeView

```
    private void selectTreeViewItem(int dataGridViewRowIndex)
    {
        expandAllTreeViewNodes();
        setTreeViewItem(dataGridViewRowIndex);
    }

    private void setTreeViewItem(int dataGridViewRowIndex)
    {
        int iterator = 0;
        TreeNode tempNode = testStepTreeView.Nodes[iterator];
        //don't need to actually return the integer...
        iterator = findNode(tempNode, dataGridViewRowIndex, iterator);
        testStepTreeView.Focus();
        nodeFound = false;
    }

    private void expandAllTreeViewNodes()
    {
        if (testStepTreeView.Nodes.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode x in testStepTreeView.Nodes)
            {
                expandNode(x);
            }
        }
    }

    private void expandNode(TreeNode x)
    {
        if (x.IsExpanded == false)
        {
            x.Expand();
        }
        if (x.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode y in x.Nodes)
            {
                expandNode(y);
            }
        }
    }

    private int findNode(TreeNode tempNode, int dataGridViewRowIndex, int iterator)
    {

        if (iterator > dataGridViewRowIndex)
        {
            return iterator;
        }
        if (iterator == dataGridViewRowIndex)
        {
            testStepTreeView.SelectedNode = tempNode;
            nodeFound = true;
            return iterator;
        }

        if (tempNode.Nodes.Count != 0)
        {
            iterator++;
            if (iterator > dataGridViewRowIndex)
            {
                return iterator;
            }
            if (nodeFound == false)
            {
                iterator = findNode(tempNode.Nodes[0], dataGridViewRowIndex, iterator);
            }
        }

        if (tempNode.NextNode != null)
        {
            iterator++;
            if (iterator > dataGridViewRowIndex)
            {
                return iterator;
            }
            if (nodeFound == false)
            {
                iterator = findNode(tempNode.NextNode, dataGridViewRowIndex, iterator);
            }

        }
        return iterator;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using  Node.Select(), it will select the node and highlight it too.

focus will not work here.