# Expanding/selecting a treeview node when it is not currently visible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a requirement to change the selected node in a treeview which is hosted in a separate tab.
Further more, if the parent node is not expanded, I wish to expand the node.

After about an hour of fruitless searching through SO, Google, et al, I have decided to post a question.

I can find and expand the required node when it is all visible, but when the treeveiw is obscured by another tab item, it doesn't update. I'm also not entirely sure that the item is being 'selected' - in the debugger it says ISelected is true, and the IsExpanded property of the parent is also true.

I have simplified down my actual problem in the following lines of code:

XAML (Tab control which has two items, one is a button to reproduce the problem, and a treeview which should be updated):

```
<Window x:Class="TreeviewTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Select">
            <Button Content="Select Delta!" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tree">
            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding NodesDisplay}" Name ="treTest">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildrenDisplay}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

MainWindow code:

```
namespace TreeviewTest
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Nodes { get; set; }

        public ICollectionView NodesDisplay { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Nodes = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>
            {
                new TreeNode(new List<TreeLeaf>
                    {
                        new TreeLeaf{Name = "Alpha"},
                        new TreeLeaf{Name = "Beta"}
                    }){ Name = "One" },
                new TreeNode(new List<TreeLeaf>
                    {
                        new TreeLeaf{Name = "Delta"},
                        new TreeLeaf{Name = "Gamma"}
                    }){ Name = "Two" }

            };
            NodesDisplay = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Nodes);
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public class TreeNode
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<TreeLeaf> Children { get; private set; }

            public ICollectionView ChildrenDisplay { get; private set; }

            public TreeNode(IEnumerable<TreeLeaf> leaves)
            {
                Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeLeaf>(leaves);
                ChildrenDisplay = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Children);
            }
        }

        public class TreeLeaf
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            EnsureCanIterateThroughCollection(treTest);
            var rootLevelToSelect = Nodes.First(x => x.Name == "Two");
            TreeViewItem root = treTest.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(rootLevelToSelect) as TreeViewItem;

            EnsureCanIterateThroughCollection(root);
            var leafLevelToSelect = rootLevelToSelect.Children.First(x => x.Name == "Delta");
            TreeViewItem leaf = root.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(leafLevelToSelect) as TreeViewItem;

            if (!root.IsExpanded)
                root.IsExpanded = true;

            leaf.IsSelected = true;
            ReflectivelySelectTreeviewItem(leaf);
        }

        //Got this from another SO post - not sure is setting IsSelected on the node is actually doing what I think it is...
        private static void ReflectivelySelectTreeviewItem(TreeViewItem node)
        {
            MethodInfo selectMethod = typeof(TreeViewItem).GetMethod("Select", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            selectMethod.Invoke(node, new object[] { true });
        }

        private static void EnsureCanIterateThroughCollection(ItemsControl itemsControl)
        {
            if (itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.NotStarted)
            ForceGenerateChildContent(itemsControl);
        }

        private static void ForceGenerateChildContent(ItemsControl itemsControl)
        {
            itemsControl.ApplyTemplate();

            IItemContainerGenerator generator = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator;

            GeneratorPosition position = generator.GeneratorPositionFromIndex(0);
            using (generator.StartAt(position, GeneratorDirection.Forward, true))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsControl.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    DependencyObject dp = generator.GenerateNext();
                    generator.PrepareItemContainer(dp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also - another XAML snippet which does the same thing, but where the treeview is visible - you should be able to see the treeview expand and the item selected

```
<Window x:Class="TreeviewTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Select Delta!" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding NodesDisplay}" Name ="treTest" Grid.Row="1">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildrenDisplay}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

I would appreciate any help - My understanding of treeview's and WPF and databinding is that it doesn't work as nicely as something that gives you IsSynchronisedWithCurrentItem, which is why I am trying to handle updates to the treeview manually and am also trying to select items in the tree programmatically. If I am wrong on that front I would love a pointer to show me how to do it in a more 'WPF' way!

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not as it is Winforms:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075841/how-to-highlight-the-first-inserted-node-in-a-tree-view/14076808#14076808

Comment: @JohnBartels, Thanks for the info but using winforms is something I really don't want to do (I'm actually migrating a winforms component to WPF!) I know I could use a winforms host control to host a treeview, but I really want to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a tab page is not visible, the controls are not created.  Only once you switch to it are the controls created.  Add a Boolean to your TreeNode viewmodel and bind the `IsSelected` property.

TreeNodeVm.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TreeViewSelectTest
{
    public class TreeNodeVm : NotificationObject
    {
        private TreeNodeVm Parent { get; set; }

        private bool _isSelected = false;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsSelected);
            }
        }

        private bool _isExpanded = false;
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return _isExpanded; }
            set
            {
                _isExpanded = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsExpanded);
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<TreeNodeVm> Children { get; private set; }

        public string Header { get; set; }

        public TreeNodeVm()
        {
            this.Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeNodeVm>();
            this.Children.CollectionChanged += Children_CollectionChanged;
        }

        void Children_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (var newChild in e.NewItems.Cast<TreeNodeVm>())
                {
                    newChild.Parent = this;
                }
            }
        }

        public TreeNodeVm(string header, IEnumerable<TreeNodeVm> children)
            : this()
        {
            this.Header = header;
            foreach (var child in children)
                Children.Add(child);
        }

        public void MakeVisible()
        {
            if (Parent != null)
            {
                Parent.MakeVisible();
            }
            this.IsExpanded = true;
        }

        public void Select()
        {
            MakeVisible();

            this.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewSelectTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button Content="Select B1" Click="btSelectB1_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="treeview">
                <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RootNode.Children}">
                    <TreeView.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </Style>
                    </TreeView.Resources>
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="the other item">
                <Button />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TreeViewSelectTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            RootNode = new TreeNodeVm("Root", new[]
            {
                new TreeNodeVm("A", new [] {
                    new TreeNodeVm("A1", new TreeNodeVm[0]),
                    new TreeNodeVm("A2", new TreeNodeVm[0]),
                    new TreeNodeVm("A3", new TreeNodeVm[0])
                }),
                new TreeNodeVm("B", new [] {
                    new TreeNodeVm("B1", new TreeNodeVm[0])
                })
            });

            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public TreeNodeVm RootNode { get; private set; }

        private void btSelectB1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RootNode.Children[1].Children[0].Select();
        }
    }
}
```

When you call `TreeNodeVm.Select()`, it will update the future state of the visuals.  Once the tab page gets switched back, the template is applied and the visuals are created as expanded and selected.

Comment: Hi Mitch, You're right, the chapters have to be visible once and all the root nodes need to be expanded for the tree node to select when it is not visible. I was attempting to get around that with my ForceGenerateChildContent method in the code above - but that doesn't do what I hoped it would. However, your suggestion of using IsSelected doesn't appear to move me any further forward, as I already can select a node. Maybe I need to do exactly what I just said - which is to display all the tree nodes once on load. I'll give it a try and see.

Comment: @Jay, perhaps you misunderstand.  My point was that you can keep the selected state on your view-model.  The state of the UI will then follow.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you are saying - it is certainly a more WPF way to keep my view in sync. It doesn't actually answer my problem in full, but I will adopt the vm changes. (+1)

Comment: @Jay, I am glad to hear that, what part is it not handling?

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer because adopting this pattern helped me clean up my code and your comment about the controls not being created until visible led me to my answer. What I am doing is a little bit of a hack, but I am waiting until the tree has been populated, waiting until it is actually visible by hooking into the layout updated and then expanding all nodes, collapsing them all and then hiding the tree. It all happens so fast that the end user is none the wiser, but it allows me programmatic access to the tree even when it is hidden because it is all 'there'.